# Are mysqli_multi_query php function connect 1 time to db or each query?

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

Just wonder if the function mysqli_multi_query connect just 1 time to the database or each query?

Answer (score 1):

Yes because it uses $link as connection id 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

And it doesn't actually connect - it only uses already established connection.

Comment: so it's better than mysql_query if I have files with more then 30 queries right?

Comment: It's no different, other than the fact that it's just one line instead of 30 in your PHP. It's still making 30 query requests to the MySQL server. However, this begs the question: Why do you have so many queries? Do you have any that can be JOINed with other queries to make it more efficient?

Comment: I build a statistics service for websites that allow websites to put in her website js code and I recive data from their site to me.

I think in the feture when someone register with a huge traffic I dont want my mysqld will fall... so I trying to found a results to do it efficient and easly.

You have any advice's?

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_multiple_query` is more faster then normal query.
A small benchmark:

```
for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++) { 
    // 3 queries, each one searching different tables over 1.000.000 records.
};
```

Results:

> mysqli_query: 15.46s
>   mysqli_multi_query: 13.40s